# Parse folder on date

Tags: powershell

I have folder in which deployed windows service. Every deploy in this folder created new folder with name appropriate current date and time, and from this folder happens reinstall win service.
http://screencast.com/t/gprp0ph2Mks
How i can define physical path to previous deploy folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to get the second most recent folder from D:\projects\ru\service.

You can do this:

```
(dir -path D:\projects\ru\service | ? {$_.PsIsContainer} | sort LastWriteTime)[-2].FullName
```

Comment: this string return current service folder

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
dir d:\projects\ru\service| where {$_.psiscontainer} | sort lastWriteTime -desc | select -index 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This will return the 2nd newest folder object

PS C:> (dir c:\work\ | where {$_.PSIscontainer} | sort LastWriteTime -descending)[1]

Is this what you are looking for? Once you have the right object, then you can figure out how to use it.